# Logstash - parse data with grok

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

TL;DR at bottom

I have a custom generated log file that I made that lists commands users run (along with some other thing). For that, I have got a grok script that successfully parses the message into fields. I've started encountering errors when I was asked to add some really old servers that generated different timestamp.

This is the the log on the new servers:

```
[2020-07-21 12:59:31] SERVER-DB-230 john:USER=root PWD=/root PID=[22714] CMD="echo test9" Exit=[0] CONNECTION=
[2020-07-21 12:59:33] SERVER-DB-230 john:USER=root PWD=/root PID=[22714] CMD="echo test10" Exit=[0] CONNECTION=
[2020-07-21 12:59:35] SERVER-DB-230 john:USER=root PWD=/root PID=[22714] CMD="clear" Exit=[0] CONNECTION=
```

This is the log on the old server (different timestamps):

```
Jul 21 13:02:53 SERVER-DEV-NEW-167 root: USER=root PWD=/root PID=[10638] CMD="echo 2" Exit=[0] CONNECTION=1.2.3.4
Jul 21 13:02:54 SERVER-DEV-NEW-167 root: USER=root PWD=/root PID=[10638] CMD="echo 3" Exit=[0] CONNECTION=1.2.3.4
Jul 21 13:02:56 SERVER-DEV-NEW-167 root: USER=root PWD=/root PID=[10638] CMD="echo 4" Exit=[0] CONNECTION=1.2.3.4
```

Since these are the syntax of logs I have, I think it's best to have an 'if' statement that says - if grok failed to parse, try parsing it with this grok code. Thing is, even though they're very similar, I wasn't able to make grok parse that data. I'm trying to get it working with the grok debugger but I just can't get it to work.

This is my current .conf in logstash: https://pastebin.com/QZv7zM1x

Does anyone know how to parse the second block of code into fields? And how to make it parse only if the first one failed? Thanks ahead!

TL;DR: need help parsing the second block of logs and have it parsed by grok only on failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really lazy solution for the second block; if you need it to be more efficient then LMK.

`(?<ts>%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP}) (?<hname>(\b[\w\-]+\b)) (?<loggedas>%{WORD}): USER=(?<user>%{WORD}) PWD=(?<pwd>(\/[\w]+)) PID=(?<pid>(\[[\d]+\])) CMD="(?<cmd>[\s\S]+)" Exit=(?<exit>(\[[\d]+\])) CONNECTION=(?<connection>([\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+))`

As another user mentioned, you can have it try multiple patterns.

The syntax would be,
`grok { match => { "message" => [ "pattern1", "pattern2", "patternN" ] } }`

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot to mention that sometimes, the "Connection=" is empty after the '='. Also, I really want to learn doing that type of grokking myself but I get really lost with all the regex. Do you have any pointers? Thanks ahead!

Comment: For the Connection= issue, you could do something like this [maybe]:
`([\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+)|($)`

I'm not going to sell this as a really great solve. It really depends how you want to handle it.

Re: pointers
I'm pretty new to regex myself; what's helped me out a lot is using online tools to validate expressions. I use [link](https://regex101.com/) very often.

It'll sound almost trite, but solving issues I've faced has helped a lot.

Comment: I've actualy found a solution. Since it's the last field, I just put it as %{GREEDYDATA}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an `if` statement, you can define multiple grok patterns.

```
grok {
  match => ["message", "pattern1", "pattern2"]
}
```

If `pattern1` fails, it will automatically attempt to apply `pattern2` instead.

As far as matching the second type of timestamp, it appears to be a `SYSLOGTIMESTAMP`. You can find all the predefined grok patterns [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).

Comment: Looks like the predefined grok patterns on github has been moved to these folders :
[ecs-v1](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/main/patterns/ecs-v1/grok-patterns) , 
[legacy](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/main/patterns/legacy/grok-patterns)